# Split last N elements in groups of X and the rest in groups of Y

Tags: javascript, regex, numbers, format

I would like to split a string in groups of n elements until the last X characters and split them in groups of m using regex in javascript.

Eg: 
split the first chars in groups of 2 and the last 6 char in groups of 3

```
var sNumber = "1234567890";

var sNewNumber = sNumber.replace(RegEx,"$1 ");

var sSplitNumber = "12 34 567 890";
```

Could anyone help me with this??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive lookahead for the wanted count of characters.

```js
var string = '1234567890',
    result = string.replace(/..(?=..(?=...)|...$)/g, '$& ');
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks Nina!!

It works fine in this case, but what should i do in case i need in other format? Groups of 3, 4, 5 until n-8,9,10...??

Comment: you might use a `while` loop for it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any knowledge about Regex, how could I do that with a while loop?